# navigation based on percentages

Tags: html, css

I have a simple layout but it needs to be altered to work so it takes on a liquid layout capability.

Example:
[image]

There is a left and right arrow. This is only for placement for now. In the center I have time slots. Here is my html markup.

```
  <div class="timeNav">
      <div class="prev"><a title="Previous">Previous</a></div>
      <div class="slots">
        <ul>
          <li><a>7:00pm</a></li>
          <li><a>7:30pm</a></li>
          <li><a>8:00pm</a></li>
          <li><a>8:30pm</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="next"><a title="Next">Next</a></div>
  </div>
```

What I need to do is have my time slots be spaced out evenly based on a percentage.
My overall width of the design is 1010px.
I have my prev button set to float left and my next button floating right. Then for my slots div I have it set to a fixed left margin of 159px from the left floating previous button. the starting position of slots is represented by a white dotted line before the 7:00pm text. Then all my li elements are floated left inside the slots div. These need to expand according to percentages. I wanted to set a specific width which was say 80 px which is represented by the blue in the example. Then the yellow represents the margins left and right to allow for the spacing. This is where I'm lost how to work out the percentage of spacing needed between the li elements so it spaces out correctly when you scale your browser.

I was taking the value between the 2 dotted white lines as my overall width of the slots. 657px so do I try and work out my margin percent based on that value or the total value of the design which is 1010px. Then do I divide it by the number of li elements inside the slots div.

I haven't really dealt with percentage based layout before so any help would be great.
For now this is just placement so I don't want to use JS for placement.

Comment: Updated: Just to be clear This page does not have a fixed width. I'm just using the design width to come up with my percentages. The entire page and all elements have to be liquid and adjust according to the window size.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pDPFW/ should get you started.

Please note that if you want to add px/em based css, like for `margin`, `border`, `padding` you should nest a div in the % based element and define the px/em based property there. this is basically the whole trick for fluid layouts. Always make sure the % based element has NO px based properties at all.

For example you should not have a list item with `width: 16%` and `margin: 10px` instead you nest a element inside the list and give it 10px margin

```
<li><div></div></li>
```

Comment: Thanks but how are you getting your 16% values. In my case how do I ge my percent values and what should I base it off. Can you also explain your comment a little further as I don't understand what you mean. "Please note that if you want to add px/em based css, like for margin, border, padding you should nest a div in the % based element and define the px/em based property there.'"

Comment: In my post I mentioned that the list item had a pixel width and the margins needed to be percentage. Would I still need to wrap my text in a div inside a li element like you have explained. Also Please explain how I get my percent values. Again is it based off the width between the 2 dotted lines or is it based off the overall design width. I need to use margins because the widths might change based on the text inside them. So by using margins I can keep a constant spacing

Comment: 100% is the width of the parent element and I just devided it by 6 since you have 6 items you want to fit in thus 16.6666667%

Comment: But that's the thing the parent isn't a 100% of the browser. Its the distance between the 2 dotted white lines unless I'm missing your point. Also I'm looking to find the margins percentage not the width percentage as I need the margins each side to keep a constant spacing. As the widths might slightly change based on the time that is put in the li elements.

Comment: When I say parent I mean slots as being the parent to the li elements.